# string is entier tcl8.5

Tags: 64-bit, tcl

I have the following Problem:

I want to check if a string is an 64 Bit Integer.
I can not use the `[string is integer $str]` method since it only works with 32 bit integers.

At http://wiki.tcl.tk/10166 I found the solution with `[string is entier $str]` but this does not work in tcl8.5 I get the following error message:

> bad class "entier": must be alnum, alpha, ascii, control, boolean, digit, double, false, graph, integer, list, lower, print, punct, space, true, upper, wideinteger, wordchar, or xdigit

Does tcl8.5 not support this method? 
And can I check for 64 bit Integers?

Comment: looks like you want `string is wideinteger $val`

Comment: Wideinteger solves the problem ... Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [Tcl 8.5](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/string.htm), `string is` doesn't support the `entier` class (which checks for general integers — the name comes from French, and was picked because everything else better was taken for something else already). However, the `wideinteger` class *is* supported, and does exactly the check for a 64-bit integer on all supported platforms; plain old `string is integer` might really be 32-bit or 64-bit depending on the CPU architecture.

Don't forget to use `-strict` unless you want an empty string to be accepted as a valid value. (There are a few cases where that's desirable, but usually it isn't. It's a minor specification botch from years ago.)